# suppress floats here on first page

Tags: floats

I must hand in a document where floats on the first page are only allowed to be placed at the bottom of the page (not `t` and not `h`).

I know that I can forbid all floats on a page with `\suppressfloats` and that I can forbid floats on the top of a page with `\suppressfloats[t]`.
But `\suppressfloats[h]` does not work.

I have tried

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\floatplacement{figure}{b}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\floatplacement{figure}{htbp}}
```

but it does not work.

How can I suppress floats at `t` and `h` while allowing them at `b` on the first page and allowing them at `htbp` for the rest of the document?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{b} % I would like to have `htbp` here

\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\suppressfloats[t] % works
\suppressfloats[h] % seems to have no effect
\afterpage{\floatplacement{figure}{htbp}} % seems to have no effect
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{.3\linewidth}{2cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{.7\linewidth}{5cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{10cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{.6\linewidth}{8cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{7cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{4cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{6cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{5cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{11cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{6cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{6cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{9cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{4cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{5cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}


\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**
[David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375702/120953) avoids floats `h`ere on the first page. But it does not place the float at the `b`ottom instead as long as I basically allow the `h`ere in `\floatplacement`. (But when I change it to `\floatplacement{figure}{b}` it is placed on the bottom of the first page as it should.) Could it be that LaTeX first decides to place it `h`ere, then realizes it can not actually place it `h`ere because `\intextsep` is too big and then moves it to the next page without checking whether putting it at the `b`ottom would be possible?

Can someone recommend a good documentation which explains how the placing of floats exactly works?

Comment: Worst case hack if you don't get an answer: since it's the first page, when the text is in final form position the first figure(s) manually where you want them (bottom of the page).

Comment: why not just put `[bp]` on the first float so it is not placed `t`op  or `h`ere?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sure, I could do that when the document is otherwise finished, but it is something I would have to keep in mind. I would prefer an automatic solution.

Comment: @jakun I'd added an automatic version as an answer, but I think I'd use the simpler version I suggest in the comment above. It isn't really any less automatic, you can tell from the source which is the first figure and you only need the optional argument on that one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. have you seen my edit?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good point that it is just the first. because the others would not be placed before it, right? I did not consider that.

Comment: @jakun I don't think the bottom placement is prevented in that case, it just doesn't take that option. But I'll trace later.

Comment: @jakun yes as soon as one figure on the first page is forced to the bottom or next page, all others must follow it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this which allows h later (eg figure 14 on page 10)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{htbp} % I would like to have `htbp` here

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newlength\zzz
\setlength\zzz{\intextsep}
\begin{document}
\suppressfloats[t] % works
\intextsep\textheight
\afterpage{\global\intextsep\zzz} % seems to have no effect
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{.3\linewidth}{2cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{.7\linewidth}{5cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{10cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{.6\linewidth}{8cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{7cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{4cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{6cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{5cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{11cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{6cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{6cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{9cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{4cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{5cm}
    \caption{something black}
\end{figure}


\listoffigures
\end{document}
```